# OSX User Directory - how did some get an ACE of group:everyone deny delete?

Tags: mac-osx, permissions, access-control-list

I know a little about ACLs from long ago experience, but have never checked them out in OSX (currently I have 10.6.7 -standard, non-server on a stand-alone iMac).  I just noticed that some non-admin user accounts I created a while ago (changer and Test) have an ACE of everyone:deny delete.

My own admin account doesn't have an ACL nor does a non-admin account that I created today.

I'm confused.

A) Doesn't that mean that no files can be deleted by anyone from those directories (changer & Test)? 
B) Any idea about how they got there?

This is my /Users directory

```
mimac:~ frank$ ls -le /Users
total 0
drwxrwxrwt   4 root     wheel   374 Sep 25  2010 Shared
drwxr-xr-x+ 15 Test     staff   612 Dec  2 13:11 Test
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x+ 11 changer  staff   510 Apr  1 00:07 changer
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x@ 67 frank    admin  3536 Apr  4 16:06 frank
drwxr-xr-x  11 newone   staff   408 Apr  6 02:07 newone
```

Answer (score 1):

As churnd notes, it's a default entity, though it's not on /Users, but on the home directories themselves, populated under /Users, intended to prevent accidental deletion.

It's there by default during creation of home dirs, because new home directories are created based on a template found in /System/Library/User Template. It's these files that have their ACLs specified in a property list.

On 10.6, in /var/db/receipts directory, the default ACLs are specified in property lists. Below is an example, where I'm using the *defaults* command to read the PathACLs key in one of the primary .plist files created when the OS was initially installed.

```
[root@lithium5 19:13:43 /var/db/receipts]# defaults read /var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.Essentials PathACLs
{
    Applications = "!#acl 1\\ngroup:ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF0000000C:everyone:12:deny:delete\\n";
    "Applications/Utilities" = "!#acl 1\\ngroup:ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF0000000C:everyone:12:deny:delete\\n";
    Library = "!#acl 1\\ngroup:ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF0000000C:everyone:12:deny:delete\\n";
    "System/Library/User Template/English.lproj/Desktop" = "!#acl 1\\ngroup:ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF0000000C:everyone:12:deny:delete\\n";
    "System/Library/User Template/English.lproj/Documents" = "!#acl 1\\ngroup:ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF0000000C:everyone:12:deny:delete\\n";
    "System/Library/User Template/English.lproj/Downloads" = "!#acl 1\\ngroup:ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF0000000C:everyone:12:deny:delete\\n";
    "System/Library/User Template/English.lproj/Library" = "!#acl 1\\ngroup:ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF0000000C:everyone:12:deny:delete\\n";
```

This example snippit shows *group:deny everyone delete* for things like /Applications directory, but also folders in /System/Library/User Template/English — it's that folder that is the source for how new home directories appear when created using the PrefPane or createhomedir command.

Comment: How would you override this to allow deleting these folders? - I need to delete them and ln -s somewhere else (external drive with more storage).

Answer (score 0):

That's default on OS X 10.6.  I have it too.  It prevents anyone from deleting the /Users directory, as it is a system directory.